# Json schema oneOf with additionalProperties draft-04

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to make a schema for validating a policy language. Short:

*a policy is associated with an assertion. This assertion can either be an operator (and, or, not) and contains a list of other assertions. An assertion can also be a primitive (leaf node)*.

I made an UML design to make things easier to understand:

[UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEiBr.png)

```
{
  "policy": {
    "name": "test",
    "expression": {
      "operator": "all",
      "value": [
        {
          "primitive": "encrypt",
          "preference": 12345,
          "usage": "required"
        },
        {
          "primitive": "sign",
          "preference": 12345,
          "usage": "required"
        }
      ],
      "preference": 12345,
      "usage": "required"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the scheme I currenty made:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/policy"
  },
  "definitions": {
    "policy": {
      "title": "Policy",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "expression"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "expression": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/assertion"
        }
      }
    },
    "operator": {
      "properties": {
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/assertion"
          }
        },
        "operator": {
          "enum": [
            "allOne",
            "all"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "primitive": {
      "properties": {
        "primitive": {
          "enum": [
            "encrypt",
            "sign"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "assertion": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/operator"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/primitive"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "preference": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 0,
          "exclusiveMinimum": true
        },
        "usage": {
          "enum": [
            "required",
            "rejected",
            "optional",
            "observed",
            "ignored"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the use of `"oneOf"` I'm trying to either use the specification of an operator or a primitive. But I'm not sure this is the way to go because i received the following error:

> "message" : "object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"operator\",\"value\"]"

The error message complains about extra properties which are not defined (because of `"additionalProperties": false`). However, these are defined in the definitions...

Comment: see this: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/FAQ.md#additional-properties-inside-compound-keywords-anyof-oneof-etc

and this: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/134#issuecomment-242989744

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks for the information.

Comment: Updated URL of first link (FAQ) from @esp: https://ajv.js.org/faq.html#additional-properties-inside-compound-keywords-anyof-oneof-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oneOf`, `anyOf`, ... keywords cannot be used for referencing other definitions. They do work for `required`. The solution is to declare all properties and only require the properties that are needed in the context. My example would become the following:

```
"assertion": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "operator"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "primitive"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "operator": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/operator"
    },
    "primitive": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/primitive"
    },
    "preference": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0,
      "exclusiveMinimum": true
    },
    "usage": {
      "enum": [
        "required",
        "rejected",
        "optional",
        "observed",
        "ignored"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```